# Xamarin Detect Programatic Change of Text Field

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

In Xamarin, I need to detect a programatic change of a text field. The `.valueChanged()` only works when the end user changes the value. I need a way of calling a method when the value is changed by a method which I don't have access to. It appears that this might be possible with an observer, but I can't find any information regarding how to implement it for this.

Comment: If your view is binded via viewModel and you have the property binded, you will get the new text changed event in the setter method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fortunately was able to figure out how to do this. Let's say you have a UITextField `"myTextField"`.

In the `ViewDidLoad()`method, one would put 
`myTextField.AddObserver ("text", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, ObserveValue);`

The first parameter is the value which you with to observe. A list of properties for `UITextField` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html). The last parameter is the method you wish to call when a change has been observed.

The method which you call must use the parameter `Foundation.NSObservedChange` so my method signature was `public void ObserveValue(Foundation.NSObservedChange a)` Hopefully this helps someone else out having a similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

For me nothing is working exept delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`:

```
    [Export("textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:")]
    public bool ShouldChangeCharacters(UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Check this [bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=864) for more.